# How to check if the file has been scanned by media broadcast receiver

Tags: android, image, media, broadcast, scanning

I'm sending a scan intent to media broadcast receiver so that that the image would be "known" by the system:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f = new File(path);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

What is the way to wait until the scan is completed? Any listener? Thanks

Comment: What about `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN your case you need to use [`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)) which gives you a callback to listen scan action completed via `OnScanCompletedListener` method.

For example

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                getApplicationContext(),
                new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
                null,
                new OnScanCompletedListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                      Log.v(TAG,
                            "file " + path + " was scanned seccessfully: " + uri);
                   }
                });
```